# PHP preg_replace Backreferencing

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, backreference

So I tried to get this backreferences to work, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Currently I have this string `<% size_../files/file.rar %>` and I need to replace it with the actual file size.

This is what I have so far.

```
$oldStr = "<% size_../files/file.rar %>";
$newStr = preg_replace("/<% size_(\w+) %>/", filesize("$1"), $oldStr);
```

Basically I need to get the pattern (\w+) and use it for via filesize function.

Comment: You need to use `preg_replace_callback()` + `\w` -> `[\w./]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\w is only [A-Za-z0-9_] so you need to handle other characters, spaces etc. Either add all the types you need or maybe match everything up to ' %>'.

You can use preg_replace and then get the file size afterwards or use preg_replace_callback.

A couple of examples:

```
$oldStr = "<% size_../files/file with spaces.rar %>";

$size1 = preg_replace_callback("/<% size_([\w\.\/\s]+) %>/", 
    function ($matches) {
        return filesize($matches[1]);
    }, 
    $oldStr);


$newStr = preg_replace("/<% size_(.+) %>/", "$1", $oldStr);
if (is_file($newStr)) {
    $size2 = filesize($newStr);
} else {
    //not a file
}
```